# Blogdown removing sections

Tags: r, rstudio, blogdown

I am working in `RStudio` and `Blogdown`.  I'm using the Classic Theme.  Everything is great but I want to remove a few sections, such as, Talks and Instructions.  Probably a real easy answer but I can't figure it out.  Each time I delete them out they come back.

Comment: please share your repo/website with us which is easy to spot the problemo

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you though.  I just make the document blank and it doesn't show up.